# Videos Airplay Support webapp

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, embed, airplay

I've successfully make the iPhone play the embed video in my site by using this tag :

```
<video x-webkit-airplay="allow"> 
  <source src="" type="video/mp4"> 
  <!-- other sources and fallbacks go here --> 
</video>
```

with the iPhone tested and worked fine on the iOS 4.3.x and above

but with the iPad 2 that I've tested it seem that the buttom for airplay isn't even shows there

anybody experience this before or have any other tag to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `x-webkit-airplay="allow"` and `airplay="allow"` or `airplay=allow`.